Reading Excel date columns as strings without time part
I'm encountering an issue while reading date columns from an Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame. The date values in my Excel sheet are formatted as DD-MM-YYYY (e.g., 05-03-2024), but when I use pd.read_excel, Pandas interprets these values as datetime objects and appends 00:00:00, resulting in output like this:
   Actual Delivery Date
0  2024-03-05 00:00:00
1  2024-03-05 00:00:00
2  2024-03-05 00:00:00
3  2024-03-05 00:00:00

I've tried the following approaches without success:
Using dtype=str when reading the Excel file.
Explicitly converting the date column to strings after loading.
import pandas as pd

def load_excel_sheet(file_path, sheet_name):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
    df_pandas = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name, dtype=str)
    
    # Explicitly convert specific date columns to strings
    for col in df_pandas.columns:
        if df_pandas[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
            df_pandas[col] = df_pandas[col].astype(str)
    
    return df_pandas

def process_data_quality_checks(file_path, sheet_name):
    df = load_excel_sheet(file_path, sheet_name)
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if not all(isinstance(x, str) for x in df[col]):
            print(f"Column {col} has non-string data")
        else:
            print(f"Column {col} is all strings")
    
    return df

file_path = r"path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx"
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

df = process_data_quality_checks(file_path, sheet_name)
print(df.head())

Despite these efforts, my date columns still appear in the DataFrame with 00:00:00 appended. How can I ensure that Pandas reads these date values strictly as strings without any additional time information?

The issue most likely comes from excel, ensure the data doesn't have a datetime type in excel

I tried creating new excel file and putting data as 05-03-2024. It is still appending 00:00:00

you can format the datetime without the time, then convert to a string

Check in excel's format options, typing "05-03-2024" should transform it to a date automatically.

yeah I understand but what if I don't have control over source data. I tried using few tools and it was able to automatically dump it as string. But when I try using pandas way for same data 00:00:00 is getting appended

you can format datetime objects without the time by using the .dt accessor:
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=3, freq="h")})
print(df)

                    A
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00

df['A'] = df['A'].dt.date
print(df)
            A
0  2018-01-01
1  2018-01-01
2  2018-01-01


For your instance you could do:
# Explicitly convert specific date columns to strings
    for col in df_pandas.columns:
        if df_pandas[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
            df_pandas[col] = df_pandas[col].dt.date


In this way I would loose time values if other columns have actually time with them

do you know which columns are dates vs timestamps?

I wanted to have something generic which applies to both because I have many different sheets having these conditions. for instance I had used a copy tool to dump as string in tables. It had worked. I wanted something similar

I would need more information to be able to give you a solution. if you know which columns are dates vs timestamps or there is some type of indicator to decipher between the two then you can just add more logic
